# How can I update music volume on iPhone, through an UISlider?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

I've tried to make an UISlider that controls background music volume, and whatever I set the value to should be the volume of the music. The trouble is, when I run the app in simulator, and move the slider, the volume stays that of the original volume, it doesn't update.

I am new to programming so I still need help with the basics.

Here is my viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface FifthViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;


}


-(IBAction)alertbutton;
-(IBAction)changeVolume;
@end;
```

and here is the viewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background music" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];
theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;      
theAudio.volume=slider.value;


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I have connected "slider" to a horizontal slider and the sound plays and loops. And if I set the value of the slider higher or lower in Xcode, when I run the app, the volume adjusts accordingly. But if in the app I change the value of the slider, the volume remains the same . Can anyone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: can you post the code attached to the action of your slider

Comment: Can you give more details? Some code maybe? How do you set the volume? What framework do you use to play the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an instance of `AVAudioPlayer` setup in your controller.

Set the slider to run from 0.0 to 1.0 and connect it to an action.

```
-(void)volumeValueChange:(UISlider *)sender
{
    (AVAudioPlayer *)myaudioplayer.volume = sender.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//.m implementation where audioPlayer is an an object of AVAudioPlayer

```
-(void)volumeValueChange:(UISlider *)sender
{
    audioPlayer.volume = sender.value;
}
```